# Заполнение значений в столбце выбранного слайса Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дан Датафрейм df, с которым произвожу следующие действия:

1. Создаю копию-слайс.
2. Отбираю значения в столбце "Сегмент"для заданного клиента id_client
3. Обновляю отобранные значения новым значением Масс
4. Отбираю значения в столбце "Сегмент"для заданного клиента id_client

На шаге 3 не происходит обновление записей, шаг 4 выдает ту же картинку, что и шаг 2. Уже всю голову сломал почему так происходит?

Сам код:

`df_2020 = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-12-31']
df_2020[df_2020['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия']==id_client].loc[:, 'Сегмент']
df_2020[df_2020['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия']==id_client].loc[:, 'Сегмент'] = "Масс"
df_2020[df_2020['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия']==id_client].loc[:, 'Сегмент']`

Как это выглядит "вживую":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подозреваю, что Pandas выдавал вам предупреждения и даже со ссылками... ;)

Comment: Нет, предупреждений не выдает никаких - специально приложил картинку :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df_2020 = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-12-31'].copy()
mask = df_2020['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия']==id_client
df_2020.loc[mask, 'Сегмент'] = "Масс"
```

---

результат:

```
df_2020.loc[mask, 'Сегмент']
```

---

`df_2020[df_2020['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия']==id_client]` - создаст копию соответствующей части таблицы. Т.е. вы изменяете данные во временной копии таблицы.

PS [здесь](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) можно почитать об этом подробнее

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо - код работает в предлагаемом варианте! Осталось понять почему .loc[mask, 'Сегмент'] работает именно таким образом. Насколько я знаю, первый элемент в .loc - это индексы по строкам, второй элемент - столбцы. У меня в исходном df индексы построены по DateTime

Comment: И работает без необходимости создания отдельной копии (df_2020 = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-12-31'].copy())

Comment: done with this:) следующий вопрос новым топиком будет